How do I test a Vuetify 3 select with vitest and vue-test-utils?
I have a v-select inside a form that I want to test with vitest and vue-test-utils.
<v-select
  clearable
  :items="models"
  item-value="id"
  item-text="name"
  ref="model-select"
  required="true"
  v-model="selectedModel"
></v-select>

I tried testing it with two approaches that I found here. Commented code is one approach, uncommented code is second approach.
test('it fills the form', async () => {
    models = [
      {
        id: '1',
        name: 'foo',
      },
      {
        id: '2',
        name: 'bar',
      },
    ];
    await nextTick();
    // const select = wrapper?.findComponent({ref: 'model-select'});
    // expect(select?.exists()).toBeTruthy();
    // select?.vm.selectItem('foo');
    // await nextTick();

    wrapper?.find('[data-testid="model-select"]').trigger('click');
    await nextTick();
    wrapper?.find('.menuable__content__active')?.findAll('.v-list-item')?.at(0)?.trigger('click');
    await nextTick();
  });

I can't seem to find the correct solution, the DOM wrapper either does not know the methods to select an item (first approach) or is empty because it cannot find the vuetify select menu (second approach)
Has anyone had the same problem and found a solution that works with the packages I use?

I have found an answer. You can't access the value of the underlying html but rather the component instance and get the value
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils'
describe('my test', () => {
 const wrapper = mount(MySelect)
 test('it fills the form', async () => {
   models = [
    { id: '1', name: 'foo' },{ id: '2', name: 'bar',},
   ];

   const component = wrapper.findComponent('[data-testid="model-select"]')
   await component.setValue(models[0])
   console.log('new value', component.vm.modelValue)
})

I had several days trying to resolve the same error. I hope I've helped.
greetings!
